# ReactJS CSS inline style position dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, inline-styles

I have this element in my React code:

```
{focusedAnnotationIconProps && (
                    <div
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: "#333",
                            width: "100px",
                            position: "absolute",
                            left: focusedAnnotationIconProps.left,
                            top: focusedAnnotationIconProps.top + 25,
                            color: "#fff",
                        }}
                    >
                        {annotationIconPopoverText}
                    </div>
                )}
```

this is a popover that will show when hovering over an icon, so I get the CSS left/top position numbers from that Icon (in another part of the code), and place it there, and currently, is showing like this:

[image]

I need to center this popover in the middle of the icon
but the thing is, this `<div>` element has variable width, depending on the text inside
so I was thinking of someway to do something like this:

```
left: focusedAnnotationIconProps.left - this.width/2
```

but I know that won't work.. I tried using the `calc` css3 function, but won't work inline with CSS, so there's my problem.. would appreciate any help

Comment: Please provide a rendered HTML snippet. This isn't a React question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `position: absolute`, you can use these methods to center the elements:

Center Vertically:

```
style={{
  top: "50%",
  transform: "translateY(-50%)"
}}
```

Center Horizontally:

```
style={{
  left: "50%",
  transform: "translateX(-50%)"
}}
```

Center to the parent div:

```
style={{
  left: "50%",
  top: "50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
}}
```

Comment: On the center Vertically snippet I guess you meant `top: 50%` instead of `left: 50%;`

Comment: Yes. Apologies. Edited the answer.